# Determine locks during process

Tags: t-sql, process, locking

I have a huge process(program with activerecord), which lock different tables for an amount of time. 
Now I want to check all my locks during the process. So which tables are locked and for how long. I could use the activity monitor, but I need more information.
Is there a tool like the SQL Server Profiler, which list all locks during a process? Or is somewhere a logtable, which I can check?

Further Information:
There is a process in our program which use half of the tables from our database. Create new rows, update existing rows, select informations... The process runs only during the night. Now they want to run this process during the day and I have to evaluate to possibility of that request. I already checked the sourcecode, but I also want to check the database for longer locks, tablelocks and such stuff, just to be sure. The idea is, to start that process in our test environment and collect all lock informations. But I don't see all locks in the activity monitor and I can't look for an hour over the activity monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many DMVS which will help you out to gather lock stats.Run this query based on your frequency through a SQL job and log this to table for later analysis..

--**This shows all the locks involved in each session**

```
SELECT resource_type, resource_associated_entity_id,  
    request_status, request_mode,request_session_id,  
    resource_description   
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks  lck
    WHERE resource_database_id = db_id()
```

--You also can  use <kbd>SYS.DM_EXEC_Requests</kbd> DMV to gather blockings,wait_types to understand more

```
select status,wait_type,last_wait_type,txt.text from sys.dm_exec_requests ec
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
```